# How to remove backslashes in string generated through .to_json function. Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
["{\"id\":317277848652099585,\"Tweet text\":\"Food Carnival by KMS Homemade Food\\nOn the      occasion of this Holi and Good Friday, KMS Homemade Foods invites you...     http://t.co/2Y2mO6vr76\",\"Word count\":21,\"Url\":\"true\"}"]
```

a is a hash with some keys and values.

```
    a = a.to_json
```

converts the hash to a string.
Now a is a string with all backslashes...
I know tha

```
    puts a
```

returns a string with all backslashes removed but what if i want to store the 'backslash removed string' in a variable?

Comment: why would you like to remove backslashes? They are needed.

Comment: when i want to show it in my rails views it's looking a bit creepy with backslashes and normally json files don't have backslashes...right?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is something along the lines of [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)

Comment: I just want my views to display the json file without backslashes...

Comment: Updated my answer, please see if that is what you were looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, normally JSON files *do* have backslashes wherever they're necessary. Removing them indiscriminately may (and probably *will*) corrupt your JSON file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just `gsub!` to replace the `\"` with a single quote `'`, like so:

```
a.gsub!(/\"/, '\'')
```

Comment: That gives me a hash data structure again...But i need it in the format {"id":"3172..........}

Comment: Glad I could help! Sorry I didn't get your question at first.

Answer (score 16):

It's much better to use `as_json` instead. Provides the json without backslashes.

For reference, 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I did `eval(a)` and it gave me actual hash with no double quotes and slashes although `eval` is considered security risk